# How to calculate CPU consumption of one function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a question for CPU  consumption  of one function that is written by C++ in Visual studio.
I have a function for example

```
void test(){}
```

And I want to evaluate performance of this function. How to calculate  CPU consumption in visual C++?

Thank you

Comment: What does this even mean? Unless the function makes blocking system calls, it should be on 100% CPU until either it returns or the process timeslice ends.

Comment: I suspect the question has to do with determining where the bottlenecks are in the application to determine what changes may need to be made to optimize.  So the question should probably be restated as something like, how can I determine which functions within a application are consuming the most CPU time?  So the question is really how to use Visual Studio to do application profiling to generate various timing statistics?

Comment: @RichardChambers i think `visual stdio` is just taken as example the main Aim of question to know the function performance.Somebody write some a piece of code and he want to know how much costly it is for system resource.

Comment: How is *code profiling* off-topic ?

Comment: I suspect no executable code will be emitted for this function, as the compiler can trivially inline it to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio has a built-in performance analysis tool, which should be able to do that. check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way to do a performance test is using [clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock)

```
#include <ctime>

std::clock_t t = std::clock();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    test();
t = clock() - t;
```

And you can output `t` which is the CPU clock consumption (**clicks**) of the 10000 times of test.

Comment: Measuring time has nothing to do with CPU consumption. For all we know, it could just call `Sleep` and not use up any CPU resources, although the time it takes is arbitrarily long.